# Reset achievements/leaderboard from my Android application

Tags: android, google-play-games

Can I reset my achievements/leaderboard result from my Android application that is used with Google Play Game Services?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, this is possible from test accounts. It’s a bit tricky so here some example code.

Add this in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And here is the actual code to be executed in the application. Added in the activity that is based on BaseGameActivity.

```
public void resetAchievements()
{
    if( isSignedIn() )
    {
        String accountName = getGamesClient().getCurrentAccountName();      
        String scopes = getScopes();

        new ResetterTask(this, accountName, scopes).execute((Void) null);
    }
}

private class ResetterTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    public String mAccountName;
    public String mScope;
    public Context mContext;

    public ResetterTask(Context con, String name, String sc)
    {
        mContext = con;
        mAccountName = name;
        mScope = sc;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        try
        {
            String accesstoken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mContext, mAccountName, mScope);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();                
            //Reset leader board:
            /*String leaderboardid = "theleaderboardid";
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost
                    (
                        "https://www.googleapis.com"+
                        "/games/v1management"+
                        "/leaderboards/"+
                        leaderboardid+
                        "/scores/reset?access_token="+accesstoken
                    );*/

            //Reset a single achievement like this:
            /*
            String acheivementid = "acheivementid";
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost
                    (
                        "https://www.googleapis.com"+
                        "/games/v1management"+
                        "/achievements/"+
                        acheivementid+
                        "/reset?access_token="+accesstoken
                    );*/

            //This resets all achievements:
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost
                    (
                        "https://www.googleapis.com"+
                        "/games/v1management"+
                        "/achievements"+
                        "/reset?access_token="+accesstoken
                    );


            client.execute(post);
            Log.w(LogTag, "Reset achievements done.");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(LogTag, "Failed to reset: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        //Launch activity to refresh data on client.
        //NOTE: Incremental achievements will look like they are not reset.
        //However, next time you and some steps it will start from 0 and
        //gui will look ok.
        startActivityForResult(getGamesClient().getAchievementsIntent(), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to get this working with the latest API but I'm struggling with "getScopes()". Can anyone tell me where I find this? Or what it should be returning? Thanks.

Comment: @Will Calderwood This method still works, but google changed their GamesClient api.  you can use "yourtesteremail@gmail.com" for email and "oauth2:h ttps://www.googleapis.com/auth/games" for scope (nospace)

Answer (score 2):

There's another way you can achieve this. Go to your leaderboard(s) in the game services area of the developer site. Then choose one of your leaderboards. Change the Ordering option 'Larger is better' to 'Smaller is better' or vice versa. Save then go change it back.

This will wipe out any values you currently have for that leaderboard, and of course is only doable while testing.